# Can I use "each other/one another" in this situation?

Tags: pronouns

There are people A, B, C, and D.

A hit B, B hit C, C hit D, and D hit A.

In this constricted situation, can I say "they hit each other/one another"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are correct. Neither of those terms would imply to a listener that you are certain every person hit every other person. Personally, I would be more likely to use "each other" when referring to only two people and "one another" for more, but that distinction is is not a hard rule.